# Communication Styles

Tags: custom-fields

How to define "informal" or "formal" communication style?

That is, how to link the informal (1) email and (2) postal greetings, and (3) address layout to the informal style, idem for the formal style.

Or is another method to be used? Now, i can only customize the three items, rank them for priority, but cannot define them as "formal" or "informal"